# JavaFX: ImageView on setOnDragDropped not triggering

Tags: java, javafx, triggers, drag-and-drop

I am using SceneBuilder to develop a JavaFX application. I have ImageView object and setOnDragDropped is not triggering. I am not getting any errors. For onDragDetected everything is working. I tried these two options: 1) to set it from the SceneBuilder (see the screenshot)
[image]

Second way was from the controller code:

```
@FXML public void sensorDrop(DragEvent  event) {
    System.out.println("Drooooop!>>");
    event.consume();
    //TODO More useful code
 }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What are you dropping on it?

Comment: I am dropping it on StackPane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onDragDropped` handler is called when you drop something onto the node with which it is registered, not when you drop that node on something. So you need to register the `onDragDropped` handler on the stack pane.

Answer (score 1):

To make it complete- in order to register it the `setOnDragOver` has to be registered

```
label.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler <DragEvent>() {

    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);
        event.consume();
    }
});
```

I took this answer from:
[JavaFX OnDragDropped Not Registering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728199/javafx-ondragdropped-not-registering)